# Determine the test statistic for each case

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Consider a random sample of size $n$ from a normal distribution with unknown mean $μ$ and unknown variance $σ^2.$ Suppose the sample mean is $\bar X$ and the sample variance is $S^2.$ We would like to test $H_0:μ=μ_0$ versus $H_1:μ≠μ_0.$

What test statistic should you should use to test $H_0$ versus $H_1?$
I believe that the test statistic should be $T=\frac{X¯-μ_0}{S/\sqrt{n},}$ which follows a t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. Am I correct?

Suppose we now want to test $H_0:σ^2=σ^2_0$ versus $H_1:σ^2≠σ^2_0.$

Which of these test statistics should we use?
I think that we should use $W=\frac{(n−1)S^2}{σ^2_0},$ which follows a $\chi^2( n-1)$ distribution. Am I correct?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Both of your tests are appropriate. I have discussed the t test in my answer. (I have also shown computer printout for the chi-squared test.)

Comment: Thank you sir I have just seen this comment.

Answer (score 0):

For asking questions here, you should learn how to use JaX to format equations.
The appropriate t statistic is $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}},$ where
$n, \bar X,$ and $S$ are the sample size, mean, and standard deviation, respectively.

**T test.** You want to do a 2-sided test. If $|T| \ge t^*,$ then you reject $H_0: \mu = \mu_0$ against the two-sided alternative $H_0: \mu \ne \mu_0,$ at the 5% level, where values
$\pm t^*$ cut probability 0.025 from the upper and lower tails, respecteively,
of Student's t distribution with $n - 1$ degrees of freedom. You can find such 'critical values' by using printed tables of the CDFs of t distributions or by using software (a statistical calculator or a computer program).  For example, using R statistical
software with n = 15 you would get critical values $\pm 2.145,$ as follows:

```
qt(c(.025,.975), 14)
[1] -2.144787  2.144787
```

**Example:** Traditionally, first midterm exams for a course have an average
score of $\mu = 100.$ The fifteen students enrolled this semester had scores
summarized as follows:

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  75.84  103.65  107.75  109.17  117.52  131.51 
length(x);  sd(x)
[1] 15             # sample size
[1] 13.72826       # sample SD
stripchart(x, pch="|")
```

[image]

In particular, the sample mean this year is $\bar X = 109.17.$ This is above $\mu = 100,$ but is it 'significantly' different at the 5% level of significance?  A two-sided, one-sample t test in R gives the following result.

```
t.test(x, mu=100)

        One Sample t-test

data:  x
t = 2.588, df = 14, p-value = 0.02147
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 100
95 percent confidence interval:
 101.5710 116.7759
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 109.1734
```

Notice that the test statistic is $T = 2.588,$ so that $|T| > 2.145.$
We reject $H_0: \mu = 100$ in favor of the alternative $H_a: \mu \ne 100.$
Another way to see that $H_0$ is rejected is that the P-value (probability)
of a test statistic as far or farther from $0$ then $2.145)$ is
$0.02147 \le 0.05 - 5\%.$ The method of finding the P-value is shown separately below.

```
1 - diff(pt(c(-2.588, 2.588), 14))
[1]  0.02147282
```

In the figure below the critical values are shown as vertical orange lines.
Each cuts probability $0.025$ from its respective tail of $\mathsf{T}(\nu=14).$
The observed value of $T$ is shown as a solid black line. The dotted black
line is equally far from $0.$ The total area under the density curve outside
these two black lines is the P-value.

[image]

R code for the figure:

```
curve(dt(x, 14), -4, 4, col="blue", ylab="PDF", xlab="t", 
       main="Density of T(14)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = c(-2.144787, 2.144787), col="orange")
 abline(v = 2.588);  abline(v = -2.588, lty="dotted")
```

**Test for variance.** Finally, I will show you a variance test using the chi-squared distribution, and the same data as in my Example above, from a recent release of Minitab statistical software.

```
Test and CI for One Variance 

Method

Null hypothesis         σ = 15
Alternative hypothesis  σ ≠ 15

The chi-square method is only for the normal distribution.

Statistics

 N  StDev  Variance
15   13.7       188

95% Confidence Intervals

               CI for       CI for
Method          StDev      Variance
Chi-Square  (10.1, 21.7)  (101, 469)

Tests

                 Test
Method      Statistic  DF  P-Value
Chi-Square      11.73  14    0.743
```

---

*Note:* As your first lesson in using JaX, here is what I typed to get the formula
in my first paragraph above:

... `t statistic is $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu_0}{S/\sqrt{n}},$ where $n, \bar X,$ and $S$ are` ....

Comment: Thank you sir your answer was really informative. However my question was if the test statistics I used in each case are correct given the information above. Again, I want to thank you for your answers.